# Efficient way to read sub part of a database and iterate on them in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, memory

I have a (static) large database containing timestamps and many fields (each unique timestamp can have a lot of rows).
When I want to run simulation using this data over the past and don't use vectorization (to avoid reading in the future or keep the code readable for complex models) I face problems of slowness :

- Either it takes too much memory if I preprocess the database by creating all the batches (for example at time T, I extract the sub DB between T-150 and T) I need at each timestamp in a dictionary and read them in a simple for loop.
- Either the loop takes too much time when I use SQL select like functions in Pandas or Polars to create my batch on each iteration. Also, the loop is simply too slow on Python and in this case I cannot cheat with something like JIT compilation because of Pandas/Polars/PyArrow or whatever.

I can find tricks for the memory problem by just storing the sub DB at T for example and keep in memory a queue of them to have the batch between T-150 and T at each iteration. I can also use a map reduce to make the loop faster by managing all the timestamps independently and parallelize all of it, however my 'complex models' can rely on past result so it could be a not so easy task to do it...

PS : My batches here are not simply chunks of constant size, they are the result of a select (by timestamp interval) query on the database.

I'm here to ask for your help because I feel I'm reinventing the wheel and it probably exists good libraries to do this.

Thank you

Comment: You might want to look into [Indexing and/or Partitioning](https://www.macrometa.com/distributed-data/database-indexing-and-partitioning) if you are using SQL source. But if you are using pure pandas, it depends if your SQL-like snippet can be turn into `groupby` or something else. On the side note, why not vectorize data? At least for readability, pandas support [method chaining](https://ponder.io/professional-pandas-the-pandas-assign-method-and-chaining/), and lambda function

Comment: Hello @WakemeUpNow, thanks for your answer. I use pandas (but I'm looking more and more at polars), however I find method chaining not really readable.
For example if my dataset is the temperature across the 50 main cities in the world, each day over 100 years and I want to compute each day the rolling 90 days correlation matrix of these 50 cities temperature, I have can't do it efficiently with method chaining or in a readable manner.